# Laravel/Composer getting "Could not scan for classes inside" for package

Tags: laravel, composer-php, pusher

I'm adding   [this package](https://github.com/artdarek/pusherer/tree/1.0.2) to my composer json and when I run composer update I'm getting this error

```
Could not scan for classes inside ".../vendor/artdarek/pusherer/src/migrations" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

This folder doesn't exist in the package, nor is it referenced in an autoload statement in that package composer.json.

When I dig inside my composer.lock file in the pusherer section I see this for some unexplained reason

```
"classmap": [
                "src/migrations"
            ],
```

Anybody have any clue what's adding this to my composer.lock file?

Comment: Please run Composer in verbose mode and post the output: `composer update -vvv`. This might be lengthy, so reduce to relevant parts, if you can. This could be caused by a Laravel script or task, which is running after the update (to prepare the database related stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `composer require artdarek/pusherer` without touching your `composer.lock` or `composer.json` file and you should be fine.

if you have any problems with your `composer.lock` file, just delete it and when you run `composer require ....` from above, it will be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the package, it appears that this line was in the `1.0.1` release but removed in the `1.0.2` release.  Can you remove it and then re-add using the latest version?